# How to get custom field value using search rest api

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a document library called Documents. But trying to use the search rest api like so

```
https://xxx/_api/search/query?querytext=%27Bomb+path:"https://xxx/Documents"%27&selectproperties='Department,Description'
```

I can see the fields Department and Description fields return values.
Currently i'm just pasting the URL above in a web browser. But i can't see Categories and Policy Number.
I have tried using the field internal name but no luck :(

Category- Choice Field
Description :- Multiple lines of text
Category :- Choice
Policy Number - Single line of text

Thanks i Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectproperties` is used to retrieve values of managed properties.
So you need add these columns as managed properties to the search schema (in Search Service Application / Central Admin) with Retrievable flag is checked.

[SharePoint 2013 Search REST API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-search-rest-api/):

> **selectproperties**
>
> Specifies the list of **managed** properties to return for each search result item. For a managed property to be returned; the **Retrievable flag** must be set to "**true**" in the **Search Schema**.

**UPD**:

Search for existed properties before.

In my env choice field `DocumentAttr` has managed property - `DocumentAttrOWSCHCS` and text field `RegulDocNumb` - `RegulDocNumbOWSTEXT`

Comment: Thanks. I just checked it and it has the  Retrievable property checked

Comment: So with `selectproperties='Title,DocumentAttrOWSCHCS,Created'` I can retrieve `DocumentAttr` value in the search query result.

Comment: Thanks. I have a filed called categories(choice field)  and when i try retrieving Categories0OWSHHCS as the manage property . I can't see to return the values.
see below returning null

- <d:element m:type="SP.KeyValue">
  <d:Key>Categories0OWSCHCS</d:Key> 
  <d:Value m:null="true" /> 
  <d:ValueType>Null</d:ValueType> 
  </d:element>

Comment: Why it cannot be null?